# Need help to Set Json Key Value inside Postgres Function

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, function

I need help in setting up the values for an json in Postgres funtion. The code below will get me the values for a particular key. Once I get it I need to do some modification and set it back to the same json key and pass the json down to other codes. I need help on how to set the values for any Json key in Postgres.

```
create or replace function test_from_json(injson json)
AS declare
name text := injson->>'name';
```

I am not able to set it back like below

```
injson->>'name' := 'ABC';
```

Cach

Comment: You need to use use `jsonb` and `jsonb_set()`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You just need to use [`jsonb_set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) if you have a `jsonb` column - if not, just cast it.

Sample data

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (c JSONB);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('{"name":"John","id":1}');
SELECT c->>'name' FROM t;

 ?column? 
----------
 John
(1 Zeile)
```

Query using `jsonb_set`

```
SELECT jsonb_set(c,'{name}','"John Doe"') 
FROM t WHERE (c->>'id')::INT = 1;

           jsonb_set           
-------------------------------
 {"id": 1, "name": "John Doe"}
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: Thank you. But i solved it by using json_build_object function. I got all values form the injson into variables. Modified the text for name and created a new json using above method and the new value in the name field.